# Is there some voice or speech ready event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I tried the following on Google Chrome. It'd print out `0` voices, and again print out `0` voices on my computer, but if I **reload the page to start fresh,** and change the last line to `setTimeout(foo, 1000)`,  then the first line would print out `0` and second line, `87`.

The number could even be changed to `66` or `33` and it worked, but I am not sure whether it depends on the computer speed and the network speed (for fetching the voice data. (could it be internal network traffic, as I didn't see any traffic in the debugger's network tab)).

Is there a more reliable way to get a `ready` event similar to a DOMReady event or some way to invoke a callback, so that it is more reliable? (instead of using a `setTimeout` to delay for an unknown duration and hoping for the best).

```
function foo() {
  msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(),
    voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();

  console.log("How many voices", voices.length);

  msg.text = "Hello World";
  speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}

foo();
setTimeout(foo, 0);   // just try again in the next event cycle
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`voiceschanged` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/voiceschanged_event) might be helpful:

> The `voiceschanged` event of the Web Speech API is fired when the list of `SpeechSynthesisVoice` objects that would be returned by the `SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()` method has changed (when the `voiceschanged` event fires.)

Comment: interesting... at first I thought it was an event that some code changed the voice selected

Comment: if you are interested, you can also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59778957/in-javascript-for-text-to-speech-when-the-voiceschanged-event-was-being-listen of why the event seem to not get an array of voices unless `.getVoices()` is called twice